# Controller not registered according to console

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, django

For some reason my controller doesn't seem to be registered and I'm honestly not sure why...

I've been following along an AngularJS and Django development course on PluralSight. The only difference between the instructor's stack and mine is that I'm using Angular 1.6.4 and he is using 1.5.0. I've previously hit some errors (like routing syntax), but it's overall been fine.

**EDIT:**

I should mention that I'm simply following the instructor's instructions and writing the same code as him.

---

Right now, however, I'm simply stuck. I've got this routing in **scrumboard.config.js**:

```
(function () {

    "use strict";

    angular.module('scrumboard.demo', ["ngRoute"])
        .config(["$routeProvider", config])
        .run(["$http", run]);

        function config($routeProvider) {

            $routeProvider
                .when('/', {
                    templateUrl: "/static/html/scrumboard.html",
                    controller:  "ScrumboardController",
                })
                .when('/login', {
                    templateUrl: "/static/html/login.html",
                    controller:  "LoginController",
                })
                .otherwise('/');
        }

        function run($http) {
            $http.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
            $http.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
        }
})();
```

And this controller for **login.html**:

```
(function() {

    "use strict";

    angular.module("scrumboard.demo", [])
        .controller("LoginController",
                    ["$scope", "$http", "$location", LoginController]);

    function LoginController($scope, $http, $location) {

        $scope.login = function () {

            $http.post('/auth_api/login/', $scope.user)
                .then(function (response){
                    $location.url("/");
                },
                function(error) {
                    //failure
                    $scope.login_error = "Invalid username or password";
                });
        };
    };

})();
```

When navigating to `localhost:8000/#!/login` I can see my form:

```
<form ng-submit="login()">
    <div style="...">{{ login_error }}</div>
    <div>
        <label>Username</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="user.username"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" ng-model="user.password"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

But for some strange reason my console keeps telling me that my LoginController isn't registered.

Could anyone please help me in the right direction?

Sorry if I'm missing any sort of files, but I'm very new to Angular, so I don't really know what to add.

If you need any additional information, please tell me!

Comment: Can you show the order of your script tags loading in index.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `[]` from your controller's defination for `login.html`.

```
angular.module("scrumboard.demo")
    .controller("LoginController",
                ["$scope", "$http", "$location", LoginController]);
```

Comment: As mentioned on the other answer I have tried both with and without the `[]`, but the route still seems to be throwing the same hissyfit...

Comment: @geostocker did you have the same code for `ScrumboardController`, if so move `[]` there too.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring the module `scrumboard.demo` twice.

Remove the `[]` in

```
 angular.module("scrumboard.demo")
        .controller("LoginController",
                    ["$scope", "$http", "$location", LoginController]);
```

Without the second argument of `angular.module()` it is a getter, otherwise it is a setter

Comment: That's what I thought too, but even without the `[]` it throws the same hissyfit. I added the `[]` to check if it would make any sort of difference. Thanks for the advice though! :)

Comment: What happens when you roll back to same version as in tutorial...and make sure `ngRoute` version matches also?

Comment: Also did you forget to include the file that `LoginController` is in?

Answer (score 0):

In the entry point html, the script tag for file scrumboard.config.js should precede the file controller file. Also as @charlietfl said declaring twice should be removed.

Like this,

```
<script src="your_path/scrumboard.config.js"></script>
<script src="your_path/scrumboard.controller.js"></script>
```

Hope this would rectify the problem.